# How to draw time based graphs using ios-charts

Tags: ios-charts

I'm trying to draw a temperature graph using iso-charts where the x axis data would be set from a server timestamp but the labels would be readable text.

For instance the graph x-axis label would start at Monday 00:00 and end Tuesday 12pm but the LineChartDataSet would be a collection of temperature (y-axis) and timestamps for the x

To display the timestamp I have a custom valueFormatter set as follow (which works great)
lineChartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = timestampXAxisFormatter() //converts timestamp to Date string

My question: The LineChartDataSet seems to be indexed based which is causing some trouble: if I have 4 data points such as (9am, 10), (9:15am, 11), (12pm, 15), (1pm, 16) the 4 points are set in the chart at regular intervals (I was expecting 2 points to be on the left side of the graph and then last 2 points on the right side) - Is there a way to have a data set that is based on the x value instead of the index?

I saw ChartData has an init that takes an array of NSObjects but then it converts it to Strings...Thanks in advance for any suggestions you may have!

Answer (score 3):

There is no good way to solve it, as you figured out the x axis is index based.

You have two options:

1. insert many x values between each real x value, like between 9:00 and 9:15, you manually insert 9:01, 9:02, ..., 9:14, but don't add any entry at these values, just ignore it and continue. ios-charts will skip if no entry found and go to next. This will works fine, if you don't have a large number of values to insert. I tried ~1000 values, the performance is acceptable.
2. you create your own chart, using two y axis, one as x axis and one as y axis, so the distances to 0 point are calculated by value. However this requires you understand the ios-chart logic deeply. If you succeed, you are more than welcome to file a PR.